GACK Error SFDC can’t help with
These are the two GACK codes: 2097016231 and 2074278169
Does anybody have experience with dealing with this and navigating SFDC support being unfamiliar or happen to know what they reference?

Got experience, but none that actually helps here. There are a few SF employees who visit this site that might be able to help. No other users are likely to have information around those particular numbers, but editing the question to explain what you're doing could possibly help. I've hit a gack before that was clearly a platform bug and found a workaround for it.

Back in my support days level 1 and 2 reps didn't have access to the code definitions, I suspect that's still the case; there wasn't an accessible database that you could search the number and see what caused it. SF support should have asked for the steps so they can try and duplicate which would narrow down the issue. Like Matt said you can do the same and we can try to see what you did wrong.

Are you using gearset for deployment?

Have you escalated the case?

@Vinay Yes. We are.
